# If an element had removed from linear independent list then will rest of the list remain as linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let say $(v_1,\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_m)$ is a linearly independent list. Then if we remove $v_j$th term, will the remaining $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$ list be still linearly independent? Is there a precise theorem about this, or just a lemma?

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is immediate from definition of linearly independence and would barely qualify to be a lemma.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, How? I couldn't get how could you deduced from definition?

Comment: In the definition, a choice of coefficients $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ is given. It suffices to take $\alpha_i=0$ if the element $v_i$ is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(v_1, ... , v_j, ... , v_n)$ is linearly independent, but removing $v_j$ from the list to obtain $(v_1, ... , v_n)$ is linearly dependent.

This implies that for some $v_k \in (v_1,...,v_n)$ we have:

$v_k = a_1v_1 + ... a_{k-1}v_{k-1} + a_{k+1}v_{k+1} ... + a_nv_n$

for some choice of the $a_i$'s not all $0$. But if that were the case then we could write $v_k$ as a linear combination of the elements of $(v_1, ... , v_j, ... v_n)$ excluding $v_k$ by the same linear combination as above by taking $a_j = 0$, contradiciting that $(v_1, ... , v_j, ... v_n)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can show that if there is a none trivial linear dependency in the new set:
$\sum_{i\neq j}a_{i}v_{i}=0$
the same equality can be used to show the original set is linear dependent.
therefore if the first set is independent, the second one has to be